# XSD Validation of XML: Cannot find the declaration of element

Tags: xml, xsd

I've been messing around with XML validation via xsd but I'm still newbie. I try validate this xml and it pops me this error: *cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'customers'. [5]*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<customers xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://w3schools.com requested_customer.xsd">

 <customer name="Vladimir Putin" address="St. Petersburg, wadim street 23, Russia"/>
</customers>
```

and the XSD

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xs:element name="customers">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="customer">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="address"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post the contents of the XSD as well?

Comment: Here you go! It might be from the XSD?

Comment: xsi:schemaLocation="WRONG NAMESPACE requested_customers.xsd" -- Your schema should have a targetNamespace attribute. The value of this targetNamespace should be what you use in the schemaLocation value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing first, your XML doesn't uses XML namespaces for its content, so to reference an XSD's file location without a target namespace you should use the [xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256139.aspx) attribute instead.

Secondly, you have to make sure that the location of the XSD file is known to, and accessible by, the validating program.

Your XML/XSD combo is perfectly valid.

Comment: Hello, I've been asked to do a coursework with XML that has namespace and I need to define one. Is this simple to do? Thank you!!

Comment: Also see this [W3Schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_example.asp) for more about `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`.

Comment: @user1959493, it could be easy to start. Say you want to add a namespace `urn:tempuri-org` to what you've done so far. All you need to do is i) add targetNamespace="urn:tempuri-org" xmlns="urn:tempuri-org" attributes to your XSD file, xs:schema element, ii) add xmlns="urn:tempuri-org" attribute to your `customers` element and iii) replace `http://w3schools.com` with `urn:tempuri-org` in the xsi:schemaLocation attribute's value. Now, namespaces may prove confusing, and given the error you've had, I would recommend to spend a little time reading through some XML namespace articles...

Comment: @PetruGardea You provide great answers! I'm wondering what tools you use to check xml and schema validity.   I create actual files and run a commandline tool - but it would be more convenient to cut-and-paste to a webpage.  But all the online validators are very limited... Do you know of an online xml validator that will handle issues like the one in this question properly?  e.g. loading from a `schemaLocation` instead of specifying the schema explicitly; having more than one schema. Thanks!

Comment: @13ren, thank you for your kind words. I am using my own tooling, GUI based, to deal with what you see here; however, it is desktop based. xsi:*schemaLocation attributes are tricky, they're just hints, you can have both, and having the wrong one or one with a wrong value are typically flagged with the same error message as in the post. Now that you've mentioned, I believe QTAssistant also complains, in addition, and with a different error message, IF the specified location(s) doesn't resolve. Contact me through my website, if you're interested in more details, to take this out of band.

Comment: @PetruGardea thanks, heheh, I thought you might be using a professional tool, and maybe I should write a tool myself (wrapper for xerces), but it didn't occur to me you'd done both.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if your intent is to allow more than one `customer` within `customers`, you'll want to change:

```
  <xs:element name="customer">
```

To:

```
  <xs:element name="customer" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

Of course, `maxOccurs` can also be a finite value such as `100`. `maxOccurs` (and `minOccurs`) both default to `1` ([See](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_indicators.asp)). `minOccurs` can also be `0`.